# Handbrake new VP9 codec is grayed out

Tags: video-encoding, codec, handbrake

`Handbrake new VP9 codec` is grayed out and could not be used.

I installed Linux Mint fresh from `ppa repo` that is referenced on their `homepage`.

`libav and the vpx-tools` are installed.

What have I missed? What can I check?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VP9 is associated with the MKV container.
Choose a different preset (*e.g. Matroska -> VP9 720p*) in order to be able to opt for it.

Comment: That was it... select the right format -> then the option can be selected...

Comment: .webm container can also be used.  It's basically just mp4 that doesn't really allow it